# Adding a Variable to Laravel Request

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, navbar

I'm trying to make an Active-Navbar on my website, however in one category of my navbar it is dynamically generated and I can't seem to figure out how to put a variable in to check the request

Here's the code I have:

```
@foreach( Auth::user()->getTests() as $Test )
  <li {{ (Request::is('/test/'.$Test->id.'/*') ? "class=nav-active" : '') }}>
    <a href="{{URL("/test/$Test->id/view/")}}">
       {{$Test->name}}
    </a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

I've tried putting double quotes in (as PHP sees variables with double quotes), but it still doesn't seem to work. The desired outcome can be seen here

http://preview.oklerthemes.com/?theme=PortoAdmin

I just have a list of dynamically generated test names that I'd like to be the active item when they are selected.

Thanks!

- Zach

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion, I was referencing this line:

```
<li {{ (Request::is('/test/'.$Test->id.'/*') ? "class=nav-active" : '') }}>
```

I've also tried

```
<li {{ (Request::is("/test/$Test->id/*") ? "class=nav-active" : '') }} >
```

Comment: `"{{URL("/test/".$Test->id."/view/")}}">` ?

Comment: Just simply write : `<li {{ (Request::is("/test/$Test->id/*") ? "class='nav-active'" : '') }} >`. It will work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the first slash

```
<li "{{ Request::is('test/'.$Test->id.'/*') ? "class=nav-active" : "" }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to append a variable to a string. You can use the [String Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
{{URL("/test/".$Test->id."/view/")}}
```